# Is the DHCP 60 unsecure?

Tags: dhcp, isp, pppoe

My ISP provider request to enable `DHCP 60` mode.
As I am not aware of the consequences, I would like to know if it is unsecure ?

Does the PPPoe more secure vs DHCP (between ISP and a user) ?

Comment: Ask your ISP? ...

Comment: DHCP option 60 is the “Vendor Class Identifier”. However, your question makes no mention of further context or where you’d enable this. It’s not related to authentication either.

Comment: I must enable it a my router. VDI ?. Data link with fiber.